# 500 Error for "The results are in! See the 2018 Developer Survey results."

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, 500-server-error

There is a news announcement banner at the top of Stack Overflow, but clicking this link (https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/) displays:

> Error.
>
> An error occurred while processing your request.

Developer tools reports a 500 error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
insights.stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: It's not broken for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: That link works fine for me on IE11.

Comment: I'm actually getting an error now using Android Dolphin. It worked fine this morning though.

Comment: I'm getting [the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y3N2.png) with Chrome on Mac.

Comment: I checked with Chrome on Windows 10, Chrome on Android, and it worked.

Comment: Alright, if others are confirming the error, how about not downvoting my question?

Comment: This should have been posted on Stack Overflow :P

Comment: I thought meta was for posting about issues with the stackoverflow family of sites?

Comment: There is meta.SE for all meta sites and meta.SO specific to StackOverflow. Duplicate question from there: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364629/is-the-2018-survey-results-page-not-working-for-anyone-else

Comment: Sigh, it's all quite confusing, all these domains and subdomains. I have a hard time discerning what the purpose is of some of these sites, and I'm not alone, judging from the number of times questions get pushed to other sites.

Comment: @Exit despite popular believe you can post bugs on any meta. Only when it comes to site specific policies, moderation, behavior etc the site specific meta is the preferred place to post. So for this specific post you shouldn't be pushed around at all. Sorry for that.

Comment: This is server side error, browser isn't relevant. There was a short, temporary, glitch, on that domain, it happens. We should not report one time errors, only when it last for long time (e.g. 15 minutes) without any other notice.

Comment: I disagree, I believe it was constructive to point it out, especially after it was discovered that the problem was not limited to me. As for it being a server side error, that does't mean it is not browser related - you only need to add a condition to check for user agent and if the code within that condition is messed up, like trying to call a non-existent function, then it would create such an error for specific browsers. The other post that @BDL mentioned illustrated that specifc browsers indeed were being affected.

Comment: it works for me too i am using chrome 64 bit

Comment: Working for me now (chrome 32 bit)